# PHP, uploaded image url is not stored in database. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a form for an admin to upload product details. All the fields are stored correctly except for the image file path. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

the image is stored in the images folder but the path is not stored in the database.

Form:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inventoryList" name="inventoryList">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
    <tr><td width="20%" align="right"><h3>Products Table</h3></td></tr>
    <!-- item_code -->
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Item Code</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="item_code" type="text" id="item_code" size="20" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
    <!-- item_name -->
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Product Name</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="item_name" type="text" id="item_name" size="64" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- brand_name -->
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Brand Name</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="brand_name" type="text" id="brand_name" size="20" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
    <!-- model_number -->
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Model Number</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="model_number" type="text" id="model_number" size="20" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- weight -->
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Weight</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="weight" type="text" id="weight" size="20" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- dimension -->
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Dimension</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="dimension" type="text" id="dimension" size="20" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- description -->
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Product Description</td>
    <td><label>
      <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="64" rows="5"></textarea>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <!-- category -->
    <td align="right">Category</td>
    <td><label>
      <select name="category" id="category">
      <option value="CellPhone">Smart Phone</option>
      <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
      </select>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- quantity -->
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Quantity</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" size="20" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <!-- price -->
    <td align="right">Product Price &euro;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="12" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- image -->
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Product Image</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="file" name="imagename" id="imagename" />
    </label></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add This Item Now" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PHP Script:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $random_name = rand();
    $sql1="INSERT INTO products
    (item_code, item_name, brand_name, model_number, weight, dimension, description, category, quantity, price, imagename) 
    VALUES 
    ('$_POST[item_code]','$_POST[item_name]','$_POST[brand_name]',
    '$_POST[model_number]', '$_POST[weight]', '$_POST[dimension]', '$_POST[description]','$_POST[category]', 
    '$_POST[quantity]','$_POST[price]', '$_POST[imagename]')";

    mysqli_query($connect,$sql1);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagename']['tmp_name'], "../images/$random_name.jpg");
    header("location: inventory.php"); 
    exit(); 
}
```

Image showing missing file path:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the value of $_POST['imagename'] before inserting?
You use $_FILES['imagename'] after that!
By the way, you should be careful as your insert statement is quite vulnerable to sql injections, I assume you are just testing but try to avoid using a poster value directly in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$_POST[imagename]** does not exist at all because the image is not in the **$_POST** Variable but in the **$_FILES** Variable.

So, you have to do this a little differently like so:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $random_name = rand();
            $sql1        = "INSERT INTO products
                        (item_code, item_name, brand_name, model_number, weight, dimension, description, category, quantity, price, imagename) 
                        VALUES 
                        ('$_POST[item_code]','$_POST[item_name]','$_POST[brand_name]',
                        '$_POST[model_number]', '$_POST[weight]', '$_POST[dimension]', '$_POST[description]','$_POST[category]', 
                        '$_POST[quantity]','$_POST[price]', ";  //'$_POST[imagename]')

            //FIRST UPLOAD THE IMAGE AND IF THAT WORKS; THEN ADD THE IMAGE URL TO YOUR QUERY:
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagename']['tmp_name'], "../images/$random_name.jpg")){ 
                // APPEND THE IMAGE URL TO THE QUERY & EXECUTE IT
                $sql1   .=  "../images/{$random_name}.jpg" . ")"; 
                mysqli_query($connect, $sql1);          
            }
            header("location: inventory.php");
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: This post makes it sound like the OP should just use `$_FILES` rather than `$_POST` (just in the description of the code, not the actual snippet). This isn't the case, as the OP is making the new filename with the `$random_name` variable.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma Would you mind to shed more light? His code is relatively ok (as you can see) I just saw that he was doing $_POST['imagename'] whereas the image comes from the $_FILES Global. Perhaps, i should have rephrased it differently however; i would be glad if you can enlighten me on what I wrote, said or did wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is with the value that you are trying to insert into the database.**

You can't insert `$_POST["imagename"]`, as *it does not exist*. You haven't posted the image name along with the rest of the form using the `$_POST` superglobal, but instead you are making it on-the-fly with the the code at the top of your snippet, `$random_name = rand()`.

So, you need to insert the result of **that** into your database,  not `$_POST["imagename"]`.

Here's your new `INSERT INTO` statement:

```
$random_name = rand();
$sql1="INSERT INTO products
(item_code, item_name, brand_name, model_number, weight, dimension, description, category, quantity, price, imagename) 
VALUES 
('$_POST[item_code]','$_POST[item_name]','$_POST[brand_name]',
'$_POST[model_number]', '$_POST[weight]', '$_POST[dimension]', '$_POST[description]','$_POST[category]', 
'$_POST[quantity]','$_POST[price]', '$random_name')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the "imagename item" in the `post` array because you sent it like a file.

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $random_name = rand();
    $file_name = "../images/$random_name.jpg";

    $sql1="INSERT INTO products
(item_code, item_name, brand_name, model_number, weight, dimension, description, category, quantity, price, imagename) 
VALUES 
('$_POST[item_code]','$_POST[item_name]','$_POST[brand_name]',
'$_POST[model_number]', '$_POST[weight]', '$_POST[dimension]', '$_POST[description]','$_POST[category]', 
'$_POST[quantity]','$_POST[price]', '$file_name')";

    mysqli_query($connect,$sql1);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagename']['tmp_name'], $file_name);

    header("location: inventory.php"); 
    exit();
}
```